# DoubleAnimation when animating an element does not set the final Left and Top values

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to animate / move a rectangle using a DoubleAnimation. When this animation is complete, I start another DoubleAnimation, but the second animations starts from the initial position of the rectangle (before the first animation started).

Here is the XAML file:

```
<Canvas>
    <Rectangle x:Name="myImage"
        Canvas.Left="10"
        Canvas.Top="10"
        Width="100"
        Height="100"
        Fill="Red">
    </Rectangle>
</Canvas>
```

And here is the cs file:

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        myImage.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        DoubleAnimation anima1 = new DoubleAnimation();
        anima1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
        anima1.To = 150;

        Storyboard.SetTarget(anima1, myImage);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anima1, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)");
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(anima1);
        storyboard.Completed += storyboard_Completed;
        storyboard.Begin();
    }

    void storyboard_Completed(object sender, object e)
    {
        myImage.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
        DoubleAnimation anima2 = new DoubleAnimation();
        anima2.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
        anima2.To = 150;
        Storyboard.SetTarget(anima2, myImage);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anima2, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)");
        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        storyboard.Children.Add(anima2);
        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using 2 `Storyboard`s you can add both `Animation`s to single `Storyboard` and set [`BeginTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.begintime%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property of the 2nd animation to make it start after the 1st completed :

```
//animation 1
myImage.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
DoubleAnimation anima1 = new DoubleAnimation();
anima1.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
anima1.To = 150;

Storyboard.SetTarget(anima1, myImage);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anima1, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.X)"));

//animation 2
myImage.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();
DoubleAnimation anima2 = new DoubleAnimation();
anima2.Duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);
anima2.To = 150;
//delay anima2 for 2 seconds to make it begin after anima1 completed
anima2.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(2000);

Storyboard.SetTarget(anima2, myImage);
Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anima2, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)"));

Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
storyboard.Children.Add(anima1);
storyboard.Children.Add(anima2);
storyboard.Begin();
```

Comment: This will fix the animation indeed, but after the animation ends, if i read Canvas.Top (using Canvas.GetTop(myImage)) and Canvas.Left (using Canvas.GetLeft(myImage))values, they are still set to their initial values (10 and 10). I need to make further manipulations to this element and therefore they will fail. How can I obtain the real Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left values after the animation is complete and set them correctly to the rectangle element?

Comment: Obviously, that's because you're animating neither `Canvas.Left` nor `Canvas.Top` : http://stackoverflow.com/a/13267665/2998271

Comment: Yey! For me it worked with "Canvas.Left" instead of new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Left)"). I will accept your answer because of this second comment. Thanks!